# Splitting 2 line-in ports as separate devices?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, audio, input

I have a custom built PC with [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00K23BYBO) motherboard. It has 6 3.5mm ports on the back, 2 of which are line-in's, the others consisting of 1 mic-in and 3 various speaker-out ports. It uses Realtek HD Audio Manager as a software interface for the ports, which is great.

The problem I have is the 2 line-in ports are always routed to the same line-in device under my recording devices.

I am wondering if there is a way to split these into 2 separate recording devices so I can route them to different places.

Realtek HD Audio Manager has the setting **Separate all input jacks as independent input devices** but still only one "Line In" shows under my devices.

Is there any way that I can separate them?